# fscanf incorrectly returning 0 for long doubles in C

Tags: c, scanf

I'm trying to read a set of values from a file as doubles. I can read them as floats, but they return as zeroes for doubles.

The input file is of the format:

```
-800,0.0000000404038
-799.75,0.0000000406816
-799.5,0.0000000409612
-799.25,0.0000000412427
-799,0.0000000415260
.........
```

The code I've got is:

```
int main(void)
{
    int i;
    static long double v[6401],vprob[6401];

    FILE * vel = fopen("velprob.csv","r");

    for(i=0;i<6401;i++)
    {
        fscanf(vel,"%Lf,%Lf\n",&v[i],&vprob[i]);
        if((i%800==0))
        {
            printf("%Lf %Lf\n",v[i],vprob[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

The output should be

```
-800     0.0000000404038
-799.75  0.0000000406816
-799.5   0.0000000409612
-799.25  0.0000000412427
-799     0.0000000415260
.........
```

However I get entirely zeroes. (Though at least they're nicely formatted...) Using a float instead of double I can read in the values, but not to the required precision.

EDIT: I'm using MinGW with GCC on Windows

I can't see any glaring errors in my code, though I assume there's one in there! Does anybody know why it's returning zeroes?

Comment: What compiler, platform, etc?

Comment: Especially your libc (and its version) would be interesting to know…

Comment: Use [`strtold`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtold) instead.  If your C library doesn't have that, get a real computer.

Comment: This is a MinGW bug according to the duplicate link I posted.

Comment: try `gcc prog.c -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO`